# Cannot translate a plugin in Wordpress outside of plugin folder

Tags: php, wordpress, translation

I have a plugin in Wordpress and I am trying to translate some of the strings. However, as I have done with other plugins, I want to keep the files outside of plugin folder to avoid missing them after an update.

Here is what I have done (the same in other plugins that worked):

In `functions.php` on my child theme:

```
public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array($this, 'woocommerce_wirecardcw_load_plugin_textdomain'));

    }

public function woocommerce_wirecardcw_load_plugin_textdomain() {
        $domain = 'woocommerce_wirecardcw';
        // The "plugin_locale" filter is also used in load_plugin_textdomain()
        $locale = apply_filters('plugin_locale', get_locale(), $domain);

        load_textdomain($domain, WP_LANG_DIR.'/woocommerce_wirecardcw/'.$domain.'-'.$locale.'.mo');
        load_plugin_textdomain($domain, FALSE, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages/');
    }
```

I have tried to add the translated .po & .mo files in the following directories but the strings don't change at all.

```
/wp-content/languages/plugins/woocommerce_wirecardcw-de_DE.mo
/wp-content/themes/my-child/languages/woocommerce_wirecardcw-de_DE.mo
/wp-content/themes/my-child/woocommerce_wirecardcw/languages/woocommerce_wirecardcw-de_DE.mo
```

Any idea? Exactly the same works for other plugins I have in the website.

Comment: What comes to mind is the priority of some of the hooks. Maybe give a lower prio?

Comment: Also an idea `load_textdomain` and `load_plugin_textdomain` return a boolean. Maybe check those.

Comment: @janw how can I change the priority in the above code? I have done it in other functions in `functions.php` but not on those

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that you would know. If you can figure this stuff out ;)  It's the 3rd argument of [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

Comment: @janw Oh yes. But I tried with different priorities (1, 10, 100) but didn't work.

Comment: What do the `load` functions return?